# How to delete programatically KML nodes from Google Earth?

Tags: .net, kml, google-earth

I build a winforms app in C# which embeds Google Earth as a viewer. Like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/google_earth_embed.aspx).
My app receives data regularly, transforms that to KML, and displays the result in Google Earth. Whenever I receive the new update, I want to delete the old KML, but I could not find how in GE API. All I found is making the old stuff invisible:

```
        this.ge = new ApplicationGEClass();
        // ....
        string newKml = this.ConvertNewInputToKML();
        this.ge.LoadKmlData(ref newKml);
        FeatureGE oldFeature = this.ge.GetFeatureByName("myOldKmlFeature");
        oldFeature.Visibility = 0;
```

I wonder if this will cause memory/performance issue on the long run. Or is there a way to delete from Google Earth KML nodes?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a NetworkLink with a time based refresh to replace old data at a certain interval.  http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kmlreference.html#networklink

There might be other ways of specifying it from within KML as well.

Comment: Networklink assumes that there is a REST service out emitting KML. I do not have that neither I want to build one as it makes deployment more complicated than necessary. I want everything inside my own executable.

Comment: "A URL (either an HTTP address or a *local file* specification). When the parent of <Link> is a NetworkLink, <href> is a KML file." -- http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kmlreference.html#link.  There is probably a simpler way, but I do think this will work without complicating deployment.

Comment: Yes it does. COM calls of GE like "LoadKmlData" method allows to push KML in without complicating deployment. I just wonder how can I remove the old stuff via similar COM calls.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use ge.getFeatures().removeChild(kmlObject); if you still have a handle on the old object.

Answer (score 0):

KML is nothing but XML. I would recommend that you delete the appropriate nodes from the XML tree and re-write to file every so often.

I don't know KML that well yet. Do you need to re-load the entire file every time you want to make changes to what has been rendered?

Comment: According to my understanding, if you submit the same KML file 2x using the "this.ge.LoadKmlData(ref newKml);" method, you will have two copies loaded in the model tree. They do not overwrite one another.